# Django: How to pass arguments to settings.py to set variables before running the server

Tags: python, django

I have few services such as redis server, centifuge server that runs alongside Django. I would like to start the services and the servers using a single command.

Something like:

```
python setup.py run
```

By default, this will run all the services on 127.0.0.1 and below variables from settings.py make sense.

```
#Sample settings.py 
#Django rq configs 
RQ_SHOW_ADMIN_LINK = True
RQ_QUEUES = { 
    'default': {
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 6379,
        'DB': 0,
        'DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 360,
    },  
}

# centrifuge configuration
CENTRIFUGE_WEBSOCKET = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/connection/websocket' 
CENTRIFUGE_ADDRESS = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
```

I would like to run

```
python setup.py run 172.19.78.179
```

Here, the services will running on 172.19.78.179, I would to change the settings to this ip.

```
# centrifuge configuration
CENTRIFUGE_WEBSOCKET = 'ws://172.19.78.179:8080/connection/websocket' 
CENTRIFUGE_ADDRESS = 'http://172.19.78.179:8080'
```

I don't want set it in live settings or through admin interface. How do I go about in solving this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the ip is going to be dynamic, you can try using `os.environ`, like this:

```
import os

IP = os.environ['IP']
...
```

So you can run like: `IP=172.19.78.179 python setup.py run`

Or if you prefer, you can use a separate `settings` file and call it with `--settings` flag:

```
django-admin runserver --settings=mysite.settings
```

You can read more about django enironment settings [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I don'y understand how I can use the IP in the second case?

Comment: @Nikhil, you just set your desired `IP` in that settings file, and the settings will be used instead.

Comment: It is going to dynamic and can each time I run the server. Using a file will be difficult or are you suggesting I create a file on the fly?

Comment: @Nikhil, using the file is still possible, you just need to calculate the `dynamic` IP in your setting file when it's imported. How do you get that dynamic IP in the first place by the way?

Comment: @Nikhil, normally it will be easier to write a **bash** file to export the environment variables and run the server scripts.

Comment: User should specify the ip. Even if the IP can be known before hand, he could also specify a port. Specifying a port becomes even more tricky then

Comment: @Nikhil, there are many possible ways to achieve, but I guess if you have many different users and can specify different IPs and Ports, it makes more sense to create config file for each user (like json etc.), and read them into your settings before server run.